# splitting a file into different users and piping that into uniq

Tags: awk, split, uniq

I have a file of the format

> userid
>
> lat lon timestamp
>
> lat lon timestamp
>
> userid
>
> lat lon timestamp
>
> lat lon timestamp
>
> lat lon timestamp
>
> etc.

And I want to split the file and then do this type of thing

```
cat data.txt | sort | awk '{print $1" "$2;}' | uniq -c | sort
```

so I can get the number of times each unique location appears for each user.

Answer (score 0):

It is relatively straight-forward in Perl:

```
perl -lnae 'if (scalar(@F) == 1) { $userid = $F[0]; next; }
            $sum{$userid}->{"$F[0] $F[1]"}++;
            END { foreach my $userid (sort keys %sum)
                  {
                      foreach my $posn (sort keys %{$sum{$userid}})
                      {
                               printf "%-15s %-15s  %3d\n", $userid, $posn, $sum{$userid}{$posn};
                      }
                  }
                }'
```

Given an input file:

```
user1
23.42 39.11 2013-01-01T00:00:00-00:00
23.52 39.61 2013-01-02T00:00:00-00:00
23.42 39.11 2013-01-03T00:00:00-00:00
user2
53.42 29.11 2013-01-01T00:00:00-00:00
43.52 19.61 2013-01-02T00:00:00-00:00
23.42 39.11 2013-01-03T00:00:00-00:00
43.52 19.61 2013-01-04T00:00:00-00:00
43.52 19.61 2013-01-05T00:00:00-00:00
```

The wondering albatrosses (aka `user1` and `user2`) can be found at:

```
user1           23.42 39.11        2
user1           23.52 39.61        1
user2           23.42 39.11        1
user2           43.52 19.61        3
user2           53.42 29.11        1
```

Handling that in `awk` is rather less straight-forward; in particular, it would be painful to get the sorting done in `awk`, so it will be deferred to the `sort` program:

If the file `x19.awk` contains the (shell) script:

```
awk 'BEGIN   { SUBSEP = "\t" }
     NF == 1 { userid = $1; next; }
             { count[userid, $1, $2]++; }
     END     { for (i in count) print i "\t" count[i]; }'
```

and the data file above is `x19.data`, then this shell command produces the output shown:

```
$ sh x19.awk < x19.data | sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3n | pr -e4 -l1 -t
user1   23.42   39.11   2
user1   23.52   39.61   1
user2   23.42   39.11   1
user2   43.52   19.61   3
user2   53.42   29.11   1
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a line is a userid if it has less than 3 columns, and that your lat and lon data do not contain any whitespace, you could simply do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ cmd = "sort | uniq -c" }
  NF < 3 { close cmd; print; next }
  { print $1, $2 | cmd }' input-file
```